# How to Select Records from large table batch wise in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, offset

I have a table that contains billions of records. I want to select records in a batch using the c# `while` loop. I used `Offset` and `Fetch Next`, but it is taking too long to get results. If the table contains below 100k records, it works fine. What is the best way to batch select records?

Sample Code

```cs
int Count  = 500000 // Select Count(id) from table
int OffSet = 1; //Next Time 100000
int FetchNext = 100000; //Next Time 200000

 while (OffSet < Count)
{
   _strsqlcommand = "Select id from table ORDER BY id  OFFSET " + OffSet + " ROWS  FETCH NEXT " + FetchNext + " ROWS ONLY"

_sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(_strsqlcommand, _sqlConnection);
_sqlDataReader = _sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();


 OffSet += FetchNext;
}
```

Comment: This is the right way to do it. The performance problems need to be addressed on the sql server side. For instance, is `id` indexed? Also... are you sure you need to pull all of the multi-billion rows.

Comment: @JNevill Yes, I have to pull multi-billion rows batch-wise. I didn't understand actually from 1 to  100000 fast but 2nd batch 1,00,000 to 2,00,000 very slow. I worried how much time it will take from  50,00,000 to 60,00,000.

Comment: The best way with huge files is to use The SQL Server Command Line utilities like SQLCMD.exe (see https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/command-prompt-utility-reference-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15).  You can create a CSV file and the import CSV into c#.  The utilities are designed to archive large databases and running much quicker than running your c# code.  The utilities are also build into Power Shell so you can run a power shell to create the csv.  I have seen with by comparison running in c# was taking over 1/2 hour while running sqlcmd.exe ran in a couple of minutes.

Comment: At, but seriously, how long is it gonna take to order by id millions+ rows every time you want to pull a page? Ordering by id implies it's an integer; why not just select between x and y if you want a big bunch of rows? Do they have to be in order? Why not just select * from table? Why do you increase the fetch size every time?

Comment: @CaiusJard cannot use select * from the table.I didn't use it between.so far many persons said fetch is faster compared to between. yes I increased fetch size because i want to select batch-wise.

Comment: @jdweng ok I will check. by the way, i have to deploy this application in a Linux environment.are we need to maintain the tool  (SQLCMD.exe) in the Linux deployment server?

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-tools?view=sql-server-ver15.

Comment: @jdweng thanks.i will check now.

Comment: *so far many persons said* - I think you need to stop listening to many persons and do your own performance tests ;) Many persons will frequently be wrong. Tell me more about why you want to dump billions of rows out of a table on a regular basis

Comment: @Caius Jard the reason behind dump billions of rows out of a table is i have to copy the records from various directories using that records information.this is a one-time process.

Comment: I still didn't get why you increase the number of records you fetch each time. Tell us more about how your table rows and indexes are organised

Comment: So if this is just to drive billions of file copies, order isn't really that important. You could have the c# do the moving, run a select * and just plod through the result set copying N files at a time

Comment: let's say I have 1000 records in the table.so I have to select records batch-wise. each batch size is 100.so first time I have to select 1 to 100 then 2nd time 100 to 200 .....last time 900 to 1000 finish.total 10 batches. each batch 100 files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Id is a number and your network Bandwidth is good enough:

1. First, find the maximum and minimum value of `Id`.
2. Second, create a range of numbers to be used in your where clause (Sorting on many records is a high-cost operation. Using `Where Id > @A and Id<@B` is way faster than `fetch next`).
3. Use TPL to extract data from the database.

```cs
namespace BatchLoad
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var start = DateTime.Now;

            int MinId = 169328112;
            int MaxId = 505690099;

            int BatchCount = 1000000;
            List<QueryExe> Alllist=new List<QueryExe>(BatchCount);
            var stack =new  ConcurrentStack<int>();

            int i = MinId;
            int index = 0;
            while(i<MaxId+1)
            {
                int minid = i;
                int maxid = i + BatchCount;
                string q = $"SELECT  [Id]   FROM YourTable with(nolock)  WHERE Id>={minid} and Id<{maxid} ";
                string c =    "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=YourDatabase;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=??;Password=!!!;MultipleActiveResultSets=True";
                i = maxid;
                Alllist.Add(new QueryExe(q,c, index));
                index++;
            }
           
            long ProccessCount = 0;
            Parallel.ForEach(Alllist, new ParallelOptions {MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 100}, command =>
            {
                
                Task.Yield();
                var temp = command.GetId();
                if(temp?.Count>0)stack.PushRange(temp.ToArray());
                Interlocked.Add(ref ProccessCount,1);
                var donitems = Interlocked.Read(ref ProccessCount);
                if (donitems %10 == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{donitems} / {Alllist.Count}  TotalM={stack.Count/1000000} Total={stack.Count}");
                 
                }
               
            });
            GC.Collect();
            Console.WriteLine($"Done>{DateTime.Now.Subtract(start).TotalMilliseconds} count ={stack.Count/1000000}");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }

    }

    public class QueryExe
    {
        private string Q = "";
        private string C = "";
        private int i = 0;
        public QueryExecutor(string Q, string C, int i)
        {
            this.Q = Q;
            this.C = C;
            this.i = i;
        }

        public List<int> GetId()
        {
            var result = new List<int>();

            try
            {
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(C);
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(this.Q, conn);
                command.CommandTimeout = 180;
                using (conn)
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {

                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            result.Add(reader.GetInt32(0));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Exception>{i}");
            }

            return result;
        }

    }
}
```